# Converting string to datetime gives NA values in a column

Tags: r, datetime-format, posixct

```
calories <- read.csv("C://Users//91932//Downloads//archive (2)//Fitabase Data 4.12.16-5.12.16//minuteCaloriesNarrow_merged.csv")
```

```
calories$ActivityMinute <- as.POSIXct(calories$ActivityMinute, format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")
```

sample of data

```
At first compiling the datatype was changed perfectly with variables  but on second try to run this line caused this NA in variable values, i have checked syntax and it is correct .
 
 
       Id         ActivityMinute        Calories
       <dbl>          <chr>               <dbl>
1   1503960366  4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM   0.7865  
2   1503960366  4/12/2016 12:01:00 AM   0.7865  
3   1503960366  4/12/2016 12:02:00 AM   0.7865  
4   1503960366  4/12/2016 12:03:00 AM   0.7865  
5   1503960366  4/12/2016 12:04:00 AM   0.7865  
6   1503960366  4/12/2016 12:05:00 AM   0.9438
```

after converting

```
 
 
     Id       ActivityMinute  Calories
    <dbl>     <S3: POSIXct>   <dbl>
1   1503960366  <NA>    0.7865  
2   1503960366  <NA>    0.7865  
3   1503960366  <NA>    0.7865  
4   1503960366  <NA>    0.7865  
5   1503960366  <NA>    0.7865  
6   1503960366  <NA>    0.9438
```

i would like to understand the reason for this error and how to solve it .

Comment: `%y` is for 2-digit years. Use `%Y` since your data has year value consisting of 4-digits. Also when you have `AM/PM` information in data you should use `%I` instead of `%H` along with `%p`. To summarise, use `calories$ActivityMinute <- as.POSIXct(calories$ActivityMinute, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz="UTC")`. Alternatively, you can also use `mdy_hms` function from `lubridate`.

Comment: IT Worked! thank you for explaining it in a crystal clear and easy manner.